# How to transfer a file from local computer in windows to remote computer in linux without installing anything additional softwares?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, remote-desktop

1. The local computer is in Windows 10.
2. The remote server also has windows.
3. Inside windows they're running a server on VM.

The remote server is in Linux.

Using anydesk you can copy-paste files between two remote desktops. So, I can easily share files from 1 to 2. But problem is how I transfer files from 2 to 3. I tried pscp command as mentioned in this article, but it didn't work.

[https://www.baeldung.com/linux/transfer-file-windows-to-linux#:~:text=Transfer%20Files%20Using%20Remote%20Desktop,an%20RDP%20server%20for%20Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/transfer-file-windows-to-linux#:%7E:text=Transfer%20Files%20Using%20Remote%20Desktop,an%20RDP%20server%20for%20Linux).

pscp command wasn't recognized. I don't have enough permissions to install commands in remote server. Some servers do have SFTP feature in linux VM. But some don't have it.

Is there a quick way to transfer files from Windows to Linux?

Comment: Does the VM have an IP address on the same local network as these two computers? You may specify these IPs in your post, as local networks are not reachable from the internet (unless specifically setup).

Comment: Is there a quick way to transfer files from Windows to Linux?   ..........    Generally you need Samba installed for this to work.